# Chrome App - Options to change URL for hosted apps

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am creating a hosted app for chrome web browser. I want to include an option for this app so that user can specifiy the URL that the app opens by default. For example, they may want the app to open `http://myapp.com/username` or `http://myapp.com/somethingelse`.

Following [this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html), I added `"options_page": "options.html"` to my manifest file and added `options.html`. However, I couldn't load the app. My browser said:

```
Could not load extension from '/home/cookiemon/path/to/myapp'. Invalid value for 'options_page'. Hosted apps must specify an absolute URL.
```

Does this mean, for hosted apps, I can only include a URL to a page on a web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Hosted apps aren't much more than bookmarks with slightly enhanced capabilities. Moreover, they're legacy app types that will likely be deprecated. If you want your app to work offline, build a [Chrome App](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html).

Comment: Correct in that hosted apps are glorified bookmarks, but incorrect that they are deprecated. Hosted apps are still very much a thing, years after this answer.